# Sum of all subtractions while excluding cells with text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got these cells like below. 
I've used a simple formula which is:

```
=((D4-C4)+(F4-E4)+(H4-G4)+(J4-I4)+(L4-K4))*24
```

How would I edit this so that it excludes the cells with text? Searched and tried different sumifs etc to no success.

[image: example]

text could be treated as zero, the 2 times are start and end times of a single day, I wan't to count the total hours between those two times for an entire week (mon-fri). Empty sections or sections that contain text, the person has no hours during that day.

Comment: Not related to the question, but if you format your total as `[hh]:mm` you can remove the `*24` at the end of the formula - the time 25:00:00 will show as 25:00 rather than 01:00.

Comment: two options.  Do you want to **treat text as zero** or **drop the couplet** entirely ??

Comment: text could be treated as zero, the 2 times are start and end times of a single day, I wan't to count the total hours between those two times for an entire week (mon-fri). Empty sections or sections that contain text, the person has no hours to count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SUM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60052&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us) will ignore text values.

The formula `=SUM(D4,F4,H4,J4,L4)-SUM(C4,E4,G4,I4,K4)` will do the trick.
Format your cell as `[hh]:mm`.

This will muck up if your start cell has text and your end cell has a time as it will only take the end time into consideration.

Comment: That's simple and effective! +

Comment: Still throws me an error that the formula is wrong. I've formatted the cell as hh:mm. The formula only highlights D4 when inserted, trying to figure what mistake I'm making. the 35,00 is total hours.

Comment: That's weird.  Not understanding why it's only highlighting D4 if you've included all the cells in the formula.  Remember the square brackets around the `h` portion of the date format - tells it to count over 24 hours rather than reset to 00 when a new day starts.

Comment: Should your formula use `;` instead of `,` to separate the cell references?

Comment: Yea, I changed to ; but now it throws a #NAME? Error

Comment: Translate `SUM()` to whatever is you language's equivalent.

Comment: there is an [EXCEL-Translator](https://de.excel-translator.de/translator/) out there to translate the posted functions to your language and vice versa if you want to post functions yourself.

Comment: Never hit me that excel had different formula name based on what language the program is in. I'm so used to using english formula names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`=(IFERROR(D4-C4),0)+IFERROR(F4-E4),0)...)*24`